# Is there a way to undeploy a maven snapshot?

Tags: maven

I have some snapshots in a maven snapshot repo that I wish to completely delete. I want to delete these artifacts so that team members will be unable to resolve them if they attempt to continue to use them (they were moved to a new group). Is there a way I can undeploy them from mvn or is this a task that only an admin of the mvn snapshot repo can take care of?

Comment: Which repo software are you using (and version)?  On Sonatype Nexus, I have had to remove them from the filesystem...

Comment: You can do that via the UI. No need to do this via file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can delete it from your server, you can't really stop them from using it; if they have a local copy they will continue to resolve it. You don't really want to block them either - the whole point of maven is a declarative representation of what to use.  If they want to build a legacy version of their code for whatever reason (testing, reproducibility, roll-back,...), this would likely block that.

You could push a new snapshot and flag all the code as deprecated so their complier complains (assuming they update).

Now for new projects or updating existing ones we use a common parent POM that uses a dependency management section so that keeps things in pretty good shape.  But you have to make sure they stick with your parent pom.

Others have done some work with the enforcer plugin.

It seems people have been talking about this for years here:

https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3952

and here:

http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Deprecating-and-banning-artifacts-with-repository-metadata-td124274.html

Comment: I appreciate the idea of wanting people to have the flexibility to work with legacy code, but there gets a point where it is handy to be able to enforce using a new snapshot. In this case, the group ID changed to something more appropriate. Given that this is a 1.0-SNAPSHOT this sort of thing can be expected.

Thank you for the links.